# Why is this signal recognized as PACTOR II but not decoded?

Tags: software-defined-radio, digital-modes

I'm using SDR# and with virtual audio cable sound
is piped to Wavecom W-CODE. W-code recognizes a frequency on 4
and 24 MHz as Pactor-II with 100% confidence, but he can't decode in
terminal text window nothing "0". This is something that I can't
understand, because I don't have HAM experience.

They say for Pactor
that is very adaptive signal used mainly in extreme situation like sea
(almost never failed). I'm living far away from the sea, and using
default antenna which came with rtl-sdr dongle, with software gain "0"
can  catch  signal -30 dB on 24 MHz (don't matter if is day or night).
To visualize more, with gain "0" and with frequency [scanner](http://www.freqmgrsuite.com) in 0-30 MHz band can
catch just 5 signal during the day. That's mean that source is very
close or Pactor is very good adaptive signal...

Second question would
be regarding w-code. How come that he can recognize signal with "100%
confidence", but can't demodulate the wav file? I also tried with sorcerer and
MixW, with no luck. Is W-CODE right about Pactor or not?

[Screenshot](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AgTtpXlIRe8lhC6T94waIWaIGvDW) that wcode recognize signal as Pactor-II

I put other files beacuse quota limit under comments!!!

Comment: This is too many different questions. They may be related to each other for you, but their answers aren't. Please post your questions separately, and make sure to include more details (e.g. give a link to the web site of your "pro software demodulator" to clarify what software you are referring to).

Comment: Thanks. I put more details about software that was mention in question, and put more information regarding hardware and modification.

Comment: Thanks for narrowing it down. Please see my revision — I removed information not part of the question and created separate paragraphs for readability. Also, if you could add a screenshot of the waterfall display for this alleged PACTOR signal and maybe upload the .wav file then it would help people figure out the answer to your question. (As it is, any answer will have to come from speculation or someone knowing W-CODE in particular.)

Comment: I'm not versed in terms of PACTOR at all, but: Wikipedia says PACTOR (I) is free and open, whereas you need the patented tech from SDS to mod and demod PACTOR II…IV; that doesn't necessarily stop non-commercial software from decoding it, but are you sure W-CODE is capable of decoding PACTOR II (in addition to detecting it)?

Comment: Also, what **is** the antenna that came with the RTL-SDR? Mine came with a terrible UHF antenna, and everything that you see on 24MHz with that most likely didn't really originate there, but is  some spur mirrored there from internal electronics or via intermodulation from another frequency, or is **incredibly** strong.

Comment: Thanks to all. Think that @Kevin is right, it's not Pactor-II. After you replay I did test that wav file again with w-code, and now he didn't recognize anything, although before couple od days I made [screenshoot](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AgTtpXlIRe8lhC6T94waIWaIGvDW) . when w-code recognize Pactor-II 100% . I search again sigidwiki and think that found answer, but first like to here it from you.

Comment: @Marcus Pactor I-II-III can be decoded even with free software like sorcerer, recently IV is problem. Antenna is [default](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AgTtpXlIRe8lhDHbS2gLOUU4DpJs), they say it's Microsft terrestrial antenna. Maybe you are right about mirroring, don't know if you notice that I'm using spyverter with modified airspy driver, so don't need to move up or set L0, also signal is better than with modified driver for SDR#. You can see option with spyverter on mpeg4 [file](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AgTtpXlIRe8lhDMNwQ5Eq4PGI055) , audio [file](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AgTtpXlIRe8lhDTgZ_rc4ZFQN7nx) .

Comment: Sorry, forget to ad originally wav file on which wcode complains that is Pactor [wav file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgTtpXlIRe8lhDULQiCtL7Mb4qaD)

Comment: Around 5 MHz with sdrconsole and w-code again recognize signal as pactor-II [link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AgTtpXlIRe8lhH9rYetWirnNPP7y), that would be second signal at my place with rt820t default antenna and spyverter @Kevin Reid

Answer (score 1):

Your [PACTOR II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PACTOR) signal couldn't be decoded because PACTOR II uses proprietary encoding.  There is no open-source decoder; in order for PACTOR II to be decoded, an expensive modem from Special Communications Systems GmbH (SCS) must be used.

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience that Pactor works best when it is in a conversation with another Pactor system, meaning it is a CONNECTED mode. It really doesn't like it when just monitoring. I believe this is especially true of the newer Pactor modes. Part of this comes from the signal margins that are present on a full circuit and the fact that Pactor can ask for a repeat of a packet if it misses a packet of data or it comes through corrupted. Keep in mind that Pactor would have to re-sync to the signal if it started losing chunks of data because of errors on the radio circuit. Without this re-syncing there could be no lock.

Hope this helps a little